# How do you view only the user logged in details in a report on APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I made a report about different users and I want it that only the user logged in can see their individual report rather than all the reports.

I've tried everything from `userid()` to `getrecord()` but it doesn't work, can you guys give me some tips please?

Answer (score 1):

The user's login name can be queried using `:APP_USER` (for code deployed within Apex) or `v('APP_USER')` (for code deployed in the database).